# Происхождение слов: "горе", "гора", "гореть"

Tags: этимология

"Горе", "гора", "гореть" - эти слова просто одинаково звучат или у них общее происхождение?

Comment: Эти слова одинаково звучат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Фасмера *гора* - самостоятельный корень, а *горе* и *гореть* - одного корня, буквально — "то, что жжет" (сюда же и *жар*, *жара*).